# Emails received right away on mobile device but delayed in Outlook

Tags: outlook, exchange-2013

I have a Exchange 2013 environment which was recently upgrade from 2007. Our clients are running Office 2013 and some users are expereicing issues receiving email.

As far as there advanced settings go, send/receive will perform on a 30min interval but in my experience, emails should show up in my inbox as they come in.

What could be the cause of the delay? We have adjusted the send/receive time to 5min but still same issue

Comment: Is Exchange 2013 CU6?

Comment: No, this is only SP1. I am sure a lot of my issues might be resolved by installing CU's but I am a little hesitant to do so now that things are working

Comment: If you desactivate offline mode for a account in outlook is it working ? Seen a case like that for remote user from satellite site. The site-to-site tunnel had problem.

Comment: I did not try this because I figured out a solution, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Solution for anyone experiencing this, open up your AD users/computers console and go to view -> Advanced Features

Then locate the user who is experiencing said issue, right click properties and go to security tab. Once in security tab, open up advanced and then in next window, select to "Enable Inheritance".

From what I am getting, when a user connects a device for the first time, objects have be created but unable to due to permissions. Once permissions are inherited, things are done in the context of the user (correct me if I am wrong)